# Image Hover Changing Color and Border-Radius

Tags: border, css

I have a design for website galleries. I have an image that when I hover on it, it will change the image with a color or image and show the title of the image. Maybe this image can describe my problem (no. 1):

[image]

My next question is: is it possible to make border radius not rounded but narrowed like my image (no. 2), because I will have a container with left border like that.

Comment: Is it an option for you to draw a triangle and position it absolute on the very top-left of the image? And are you just asking for the narrowing or also for the hover effect?

Comment: Hello, just as amitdatta answer, but for my number 1 problem, there's also an image or transparent color that hovering the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding problem number one, you can try something like this. It is simply done by absolute positioning of css! You can also look for tons of plugins available online for this. The JSFiddle for this goes here: http://jsfiddle.net/amitdatta/z4gY8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="http://www.hdpaperwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/beautyful_scenery-2560x1600.jpg" width="350px" />
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>CAPTION GOES HERE</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumb {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumb img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.thumb > div {
    background-color: rgba(21, 29, 29, 0.75);
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 0;
    color: #ccc;
}
.thumb:hover > div {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.thumb > div div {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.thumb p {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Regarding your problem number two, you can try the following code. Now-a-days you can draw any regular shape using CSS easily! The JSFiddle for this goes here: http://jsfiddle.net/amitdatta/Ean2z/

**HTML**

```
<div id='shape'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#shape {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#shape:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 70px solid red;
    border-left: 70px solid #FFF;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, solved number 2 problem (which still editing it because different of what I need, but thanks for creating the shape). For number 1, how could I use the image hover too? the image is changing to some transparent color (or transparent image, doesnt matter)

Comment: The number 2 problem in fact is not solved such easily, try this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Ean2z/1/, what if you have some background-image (not even the solid green color) behind? The corner triangle will be distinct out. The solution for number 2 problem is acceptable only when we are sure that the background behind has only a solid color covered, in this case we just need to set that color for the corner triangle.

Comment: Yes, You're very right still got a problem here, because I just want the border that colored, not the fill, and I can't fill the color for border (even it always filled with a color - white). If there's no solution maybe I will create it just as an image